# Microsoft Ajax script extensions - same in both ASP.NET AJAX and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Are the client side javascript extensions, e.g. **MicrosoftAjax.js**, the same in both ASP.NET AJAX (for ASP.NET WebForms) and ASP.NET MVC?

For example, does it still include:

- Global Namespace
- Sys Namespace
- Sys.Net Namespace
- Sys.Serialization Namespace
- Sys.Services Namespace
- Sys.UI Namespace
- Sys.WebForms Namespace

although I'd suspect that the Sys.WebForms namespace might be redundant for MVC...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both frameworks share the same MicrosoftAjax.js file, but each has a seperate additional ajax file too:

MVC has a MicrosoftMvcAjax.js file.

Webforms has a MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js file.